# Facing issues passing a complex32 type to a user defined structure in Embedded Rust

Tags: rust, embedded

My rust code runs as a library, and it computes the FFT of a time sample and returns the Real and Imaginary values to the main C code. I pass values between the library and rust through the means of a few structures

```
pub struct ComplexT {
    real: f32,
    imag: f32,
}    

pub struct Data {
    fft: [[ComplexT; 500]; 3],
    ........
}
```

I pass the Data structure from C to Rust function called processor. Inside the processor I call a function called compute_fft where I pass the Data object.fft[0].

Once inside compute fft, I calculate the FFT, and since Complex32 types from the microfft function won't be accessible in C, I run something like this

```
for i in 0..500 {
        output_fft[i].imag = fft_stored[i].im;
        output_fft[i].real = fft_stored[i].re;
    }
```

On running the code exactly as it is, the flow of the program stops right here, with no errors thrown.
However if i do something like

```
output_fft[i].imag = 1.0;
output_fft[i].real = 2.0;
```

there's no problem.

Also, I can do operations like

```
tmp = fft_stored[i].im + fft_stored[i].re
```

just to check where the problem is, but this worked too

I tried the code with rust on my local machine and I didn't see any errors there. Im a relative newbie at rust, so a push in the right direction would be helpful!

Note - everything is in a ![no_std] environment